# How to determine the active systemd-resolved link number using a script?

Tags: bash, systemd, dns

Because several of the `resolvectl` commands take the link number as an argument, how do you determine which of the links is the active (current) one?

So far I have:

```
$ resolvectl status | grep -PB1 'Current Scopes.*\bDNS\b' | head -n 1
Link 3 (br0)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resolvectl status | grep -PB1 'Current Scopes.*\bDNS\b' | head -n 1` is the best way to do it!